# With Powershell, how can I get the id of a process owned by a specific user?

Tags: powershell, process, kill

Using Powershell, I want to do the equivalent of Unix

```
ps -auxc | grep Emacs

kill -9 364
```

(Assuming 365 was the pid the first command told me.)

How do I do that? I find it incredibly hard to get Powershell to tell me the owner of a process and the way I tried, getting a wmi-object win32_process and then make that into a list of processes named "explorer.exe" just started lots of explorer.exe instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this with a quick google:

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}

get-process | select processname,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

seems to return users as requested. You can probably proceed from there. Hope that helps.

Comment: Isn't it amazing how easy and simple Powershell is compared to the old out-dated Unix shells? :-)

Answer (score 1):

With PowerShell 4 and newer you can do:

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where-Object {$_.UserName -match "peter" -and $_.ProcessName -eq "Notepad"} | Stop-Process -Force
```

or when using aliases:

```
ps -IncludeUserName | ? {$_.UserName -match "peter" -and $_.ProcessName -eq "Notepad"} | spps -Force
```

not as short as in Unix but better than in older PowerShell versions.